# Approach to create service oriented application for MVC application using Web Api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am planning to create a service oriented application. For creating service I will be using WebApi and for web application MVC.
I have thought of two approach for the same kindly let me know which one better.

1. Create one business logic shared across MVC and WebApi and dont consume WebApi in MVC application. Just business logic will be shared.
2. Consume API in MVC application from WebApi project using HttpClient.

Comment: what's the point in creating a WebApi for option 1 then? All you have is a business layer basically and no need for an API.

Comment: By doing so i don't have to write code for consuming WebApi in MVC app and my WebApi can be used for mobile app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was a bit unclear but now, after comments it makes more sense.

I would go with option 1.

The first reason is that you can avoid a lot of traffic to the API if you can simply use the layer and don't bother with any APi calls at all.

The second reason, it will be a little quicker since it doesn't need to wait for the API responses.

Less pressure on the API means the mobile app has more resources to play with.
You can basically build your own Nuget packages, use them in both your Web and Api layers and you don't have to repeat the code.

Comment: Thanks. Plz let me know how layering should be done for such project.